# The products are not removing from the shopping cart after ordering in python-django

Tags: python, django, view, cart

I am trying to make an e-commerce website. There is 1 problem which has been very hard to fix. The problem:
After ordering, products are supposed to be deleted from the shopping cart. But it is not working. There are no syntaxis errors but there is still products remaining after ordering.

Here is the part my views.py for it:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart is not None:
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    if order_products:
        order_product = order_products[0]
    else:
        order_product = OrderProduct.objects.create(order=order)

    order.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart is not None:
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        session.modified = True

return redirect('product_list')
```

I really hope someone can help me, please.

Someone answered this question about 3 days ago but their answer wasn't right. I commented on their answer but they are not answering. You can check my previous question if you need their answer. IT IS NOT WORKING!

Comment: Where are you storing shopping cart items is not clear. Add item to shopping cart code is needed. This code isn't enough to give you any suggestion

Comment: what more code do you need?

Comment: How you are managing shopping cart. That code is necessary

Comment: is that from  models.py or views.py?

Comment: Provide both code